# DateTime comparison in Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku

I built this simple app to get more comfortable with Rails. It works fine in development but when I deployed to Heroku, it seems that the DateTime comparison is no longer working. Upon submission, I keep hitting that "invalid delivery time" even with inputted times in the future.

I'm using a Postgres database and the form, which I'll include below, uses a form_tag helper with a date_time field. I've also included my schema below.

```
# controllers/messages_controller.rb
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @message = Message.new
  end

  def create
    @message = Message.new(message_params)

    if @message.save
      if @message.delivery_time > DateTime.now
        UserMailer.scheduled_email(@message).deliver_later(wait_until: @message.delivery_time)
        flash[:notice] = "Your message was scheduled :)"
      else
        flash[:notice] = "invalid delivery time, can't schedule :("
      end
    else
      flash[:notice] = "Unable to schedule message :("
    end

    redirect_to root_path
  end

  private

  def message_params
    params.require(:message).permit(:content, :email_address, :delivery_time)
  end
end
```

```
# views/messages/new.html.erb
<div class="container">
    <div class="form">
      <h1>write to future you</h1><br>
      <%= form_with model: @message, url: '/messages' do |f| %>
        <%= f.label "Message" %><br>
        <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "Future John - \n\nI hope you invested in WUPHF...", required: true %><br><br>

        <%= f.label "Email" %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :email_address,  placeholder: "johnlegend@mac.com", required: true, autocomplete: "off" %><br><br>

        <%= f.label "Delivery" %><br>
        <%= f.datetime_field :delivery_time, required: true %><br><br>

        <%= f.submit "SEND IT", data: {confirm: "Are you sure you want to schedule this message?"} %>

      <% end %>
      <p><%= flash[:notice] %></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
# db/schema.rb
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2020_09_27_171654) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "messages", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email_address"
    t.text "content"
    t.datetime "delivery_time"
  end

end
```

Any suggestions for how to troubleshoot would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can also post the database.yml file if people think the issue may be there, but I believe that because I can persist objects to the database in production, that the issue is with the comparison in the messages controller.

Comment: It would be helpful to print out, or use a debugger to inspect, the values of `@message.delivery_time` (and what `DateTime.now` evaluates to) for a failing request. My first thought here is maybe a timezone discrepancy.

Comment: Thanks Robert, I appreciate the help. Here's what I saw locally when I throw a binding.pry in that controller action:
`@message.delivery_time #=> Sun, 27 Sep 2020 16:08:00 UTC +00:00` and 
`DateTime.now #=> Sun, 27 Sep 2020 16:04:28 -0400`
If it were you, how would you handle comparison to ensure the user has inputted a date / time in the future?

Comment: Well `Sun, 27 Sep 2020 16:04:28 -0400` is `Sun, 27 Sep 2020 20:04:28 UTC` so the error is correct the `@message.delivery_time` is not in the future.  I'm guessing the change in servers meant a change in the `TimeZone` setting for the server. You need to normalize your datetimes to a time zone.

Comment: Thanks Adrian, that's weird. In the form, I entered a time that was about 5 - 10 minutes later than the current time when I submitted. Is there some reason that my local server wouldn't be on the same time zone?

Maybe a better question would be... is there a way to standardize datetimes upon persistence to the database so that I can make reliable comparisons (to DateTime.now, Time.now, etc.)?

Comment: Postgres can store times in two formats, timestamptz (with time zone) and timestamp (without). `datetime` is the [latter](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/070d4afacd3e9721b7e3a4634e4d026b5fa2c32c/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb#L108), so once the time hits the db the zone information is lost (and what's stored in there is assumed by all users to be UTC afterward). Rails is supposed to convert it to UTC on the way in, and I'm not sure why it's not. Do the same pry commands return the same values in production?

Comment: The time zone set in Heroku might no be the same as set in your rails app.

Comment: I think you're both right. Using a pry in production, I realized the values being persisted to the database for the delivery_time attribute are in my local time, but the timestamps (and any DateTime.now or Time.now calls) are all 4 hours ahead. Unsure if this is a function of using Heroku or something else. May just try altering the select options in the form to avoid this type of datetime comparison entirely.

Comment: And those times -- delivery_time and any DateTime.now call -- are both standardized to UTC +0 before comparison.